# UWP "The name dispatcher does not exist in the current context"

Tags: c#, uwp, xamarin.ios, xamarin.uwp

In a UWP C# app, need background (ie. worker) thread to use UI thread to display an image.  But can't figure out how to compile `Dispatcher.RunAsync()`.

```
using Foundation;
using System;
using UIKit;

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Threading;                 <<<<<<<<<<  gets error
using Windows.UI.Core;                          <<<<<<<<<<  gets error

public async static void process_frame()
{

    await Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
    {
        // "the name dispatcher does not exist in current context"
        //UI code here:
        display_frame();
    });
}


public void display_frame()
{
    var data = NSData.FromArray(System_Hub_Socket.packet_frame_state.buffer);

    UIImageView_camera_frame.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData(data);
}
```

**Latest method**

```
public async static void process_frame( /* ax obsolete: byte[] camera_frame_buffer, int frame_size_bytes */  )
{
    await Task.Run( () => { viewcontroller.display_frame(); } );
}


// [3]
// Copies latest frame from camera to UIImageView on iPad.
// UI THREAD

public Task display_frame()
{
  var data = NSData.FromArray ( System_Hub_Socket.packet_frame_state.buffer);        
  <<<<<< ERROR 

  UIImageView_camera_frame.Image = UIImage.LoadFromData( data );

  return null;
}
```

Error from the latest method

[image]

Comment: `display_frame` should be `public Task display_frame()` if you want it to be like a `void`, and if you need to return something, it should be `public Task<T>` where T is the type returned from the method. Then you can do `await Task.Run(() => display_frame());`

Comment: What should display_frame() return?  I did "public Task display_frame()" but get compile error "not all code paths return a value".

Comment: so I returned:  return null;

Comment: return Task.CompletedTask(); causes this error:  "Non-invokable member "Task.CompletedTask' cannot be used like a method."

Comment: Sorry, I should have left the `()` off, it is a property not a method, do `return Task.CompletedTask;` Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.completedtask?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: "Task.Run..." didn't work;  seems to run display_frame() from non-UI thread. (please see ERROR FROM LATEST METHOD).

Comment: That's what Tasks typically do, they run off of the thread pool, what is it you are trying to accomplish? Maybe this just needs re-worked. If you want to get the image asynchronously and then show it with the UI thread, you could change your method to return `Task<Image>` await the image and then use that to show it with the UI thread inside of `process_frame()`

Comment: Maybe this will help you (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412984/uikitthreadaccessexception-from-await-task-run-with-a-try-catch-finally-block)

Comment: I found some class name such as  `UIImage` `NSData`, it looks like xamrin.ios project, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the `using` statements in you code:

```
using UIKit;
...
using Windows.UI.Core;
```

This just can't happen. `UIKit` is a Xamarin.iOS, platform-specific namespace and `Windows.UI.Core` is Windows platform-specific namespace and in no way can those two be mixed in one file (except for shared project with `#if` directives that is, but that is not the case here).

Xamarin helps writing cross-platform apps, but you still cannot use platform specific APIs on OS on which they are not available. Windows has `Dispatcher` as a means of running code on the UI thread, but this concept is not available on iOS, which uses `InvokeOnMainThread` method instead.

So if you are writing code that is in the platform-specific iOS project, you must use iOS APIs. If you are writing code that is in the platfrom-specific UWP project, you must use UWP APIs - things like `Dispatcher` will work without problem there.

Finally, if you are writing code in a .NET Standard library, you cannot write any platform specific code directly and must use [dependency injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/dependency-injection) to define an interface behind which you hide the use of platform specific APIs.